# How will the data files under `pipe`, `sequence`, and `unsequence` directories be stored and merged when executing pipeline in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When the `pipeline` in Apache IoTDB is working in progress, does the tsfiles stored in IoTDB be copied to the `pipe` directory, and the files will not be merged after they are solidified? Also, for the data files under `sequence` and `unsequence` directories at the source of `pipe`, will they only store incremental data? Will the execution of `pipeline` affect the number of data files under these directories?

Answer (score 0):

When `pipe` is running, the relevant `tsfile` in Apache IoTDB will be hardlinked to the `pipe` directory, and the hardlinked files will not be merged and deleted. The `sequence` and `unsequence` directories in IoTDB are where the storage engine writes data files. Pipe execution will not affect the  merging of the files inside. The data deletion operation in IoTDB will also not affect the unsynchronized data in the `pipe` directory.